# How to find consonant clusters with regex?

Tags: regex, expression, regular-language

I want to find [consonant clusters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonant_cluster) with regex. An example of a cluster is ***mpl*** in ***examples***.

To start, I filtered out all the vowels and replaced them with spaces. With vowels filtered out, ***examples*** is ***x mpl s***.

How can I filter out the ***x*** and the ***s*** too?

Comment: What do you mean by "sort out"?

Comment: What's your input and expected output? Are you trying to match only the consonents?

Comment: The term *"consonant cluster"* doesn't have a single, sharply defined meaning. You need to add an exact definition of what you want to match.

Comment: As you changed vowels into white space: Search for `\b.\b`and replace with a blank - to get rid of all isolated letters, leaving you with sequences of at least two? Like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/dT9dU9/2)?

Comment: hm, okay, sorry for the bad description. I have an excel sheet where I have about 1200 words. Of these words, I have to find clusters of consonants. These clusters are of 2 or more consonants. I just count them manually and write down the number of consonats in each cluster. 

To make it easier, I got rid of the vowels (I don't need to count them) and now I want to get rid of the SINGLE consonants, cause I don't need them as well. I Hope you know what I mean :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2,}
```

`(?![aeiou])[a-z]` means choose any character from the lowercase alphabets but not of `a` or `e` or `i` or `o` or `u`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dT9dU9/3)

- `(?![aeiou])[a-z]` Matches a lowercase consonent
- `(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){2,}` two or more times.

Answer (score 1):

Since your working definition of "consonant cluster" is two or more consonants in succession, you can simply use the following pattern (case-insensitively if you want to handle capital consonants):

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]{2,}
```

- `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]` – a simple whitelist character class for consonants (i.e. that will only match a consonant)
- `{2,}` – two or more in succession

You can test the pattern against a couple input strings in a [related regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/pxwmy6).

*Note* that since vowels are "***a***, ***e***, ***i***, ***o***, ***u***, and *sometimes* ***y***", I have included `y` in the whitelist character class for consonants above.

You could drop `y` and use...

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]{2,}
```

...if you want to unconditionally treat ***y*** as a vowel rather than a consonant; but the [rules for when ***y*** is a consonant](http://www.phonicsontheweb.com/y-roles.php) are a bit more complicated than a simple regex will handle (basically requiring that you identify syllables first, then ***y***'s location within them).

Answer (score 0):

Turning a comment into an answer…

As you changed vowels into white space: Search for `\b.\b` (or `\b\w\b` to target a bit better) and replace with a blank - to get rid of all isolated letters, leaving you with sequences of at least two.

Like [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/dT9dU9/2).